# How to install the latest PostGIS in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, postgis-2.2, ubuntugis, debian, osgeo-live

I am wondering how can I install the latest PostGIS 2.2 (testing) from the Debian GIS project here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgis/2.2.0+dfsg-3

I tried `apt-get install -s postgis` after

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable 
sudo apt-get update
```

and the reported version to install is:

```
Inst postgis (2.1.4+dfsg-3~trusty ubuntugis-unstable:14.04/trusty [amd64])
```

Since I need the 2.2 version and don't necessarily want to compile from source, I looked around and found the debian/ubuntu package at the top of this package. The available downloads are:

```
Downloads
File    Size    MD5 Checksum
postgis_2.2.0+dfsg-3.dsc    2.8 KiB     df4642773d269767e05d89df90ad45ff
postgis_2.2.0+dfsg.orig.tar.gz  9.7 MiB     0704ebb3261388bb3e532193b06982d5
postgis_2.2.0+dfsg-3.debian.tar.xz  36.8 KiB    5bdc005b6073d3f9578cf42dd0c1a22a
```

I am not familiar with this format. Can any one explain how to use these?

By the way, I am using Ubuntu/Lubuntu 14.04 LTS (I can switch to newer versions, or use a way to backport 16.04 to 14.04 if possible). I also looked at OSGeoLive, and they are offering 2.1.x as of Jan 2015.

Comment: The package you are referencing is for xenial (16.06) like this one http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.2

Comment: @bennos Thanks for pointing out the version. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have installed some version of Postgresql on your machine. I recently used these command to install Postgresql and Postgis to run on my Ubuntu 14.04 terminal. You would just need to update the versions in the code.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3 postgresql-contrib
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 pgadmin3 postgresql-contrib
```

This was the [source](http://www.negengec.com/2014/08/how-to-install-postgis-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-remote-connections-enabled/) I used

Comment: Those are based on instructions I've been trying to maintain found here: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt which depending on what the PostgreSQL APT repository folks have been up to should pull in 2.2.1 ...